# php check chmod permissions for folder

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

Hello how can I check if a folder has permissions to be writable and readable via php.

I want to check for permissions for include and file_get/put_contents, too.

I'm creating test code to check for permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) .

EDIT:Then try [fileperms](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

Comment: I don't want to change them, I want to check if folder has this permissions.

Comment: Thanks about that. I've tried it, but on windows my permissions are buggy and it didn't work, now its fine on linux.

Answer (score 10):

Check out [is_writable](http://php.net/is_writable) och [is_readable](http://php.net/is_readable). They're tailored for exactly this.

Comment: Ok, what about include and file_get_contents.I don't know which php.ini setting is for them.For them I need only the setting, then I will use ini_get.

Comment: You do not change file permissions in php.ini. You change them using chmod as the owner of the files (FTP, SSH and even PHP have a chmod command). You can read more about file permissions and how to set them correctly here: http://catcode.com/teachmod/